# Good replacement for Qt

Tags: c++, programming-languages

Is there any replacement for Qt that can be ported on Windows and Linux or good for Linux that supports OpenGL? I have to write OpneGL C++ application and I want to try something better if exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, if you do c++ GUI applications portable across Windows/Linux/Mac, Qt is your best shot.

Other popular toolkits are [wx](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) and [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/).